# How to transfer call from one queue to another queue in twilio?

Tags: queue, twilio

Can anyone tell me the steps as to how to transfer a call from one queue to another queue in twilio?

Answer (score 2):

Twilio evangelist here.

So you want to take a call that has already been queued into QueueA and move that call into QueueB?

You first need to acquire the CallSid for the call you want to transfer. There are lots of ways to do this since virtually every [web hook request Twilio makes during a voice call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/twilio_request?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=feb2014&utm_campaign=stackathon) includes the [CallSid parameter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/twilio_request#synchronous-request-parameters?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=feb2014&utm_campaign=stackathon).  You can save the CallSid of the Call before you place it into QueueA, or you can use the [Members resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/member#list?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=feb2014&utm_campaign=stackathon) to list all of the members of QueueA.  Each [Member resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/member?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=feb2014&utm_campaign=stackathon) includes the associated [CallSid](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/member#instance-properties?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=feb2014&utm_campaign=stackathon).

Once you have the CallSid, you can use the Members resource to [dequeue the specific call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/member#instance-post-example-2?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=feb2014&utm_campaign=stackathon) providing a URL that returns a new set of TwiML instructions, which in your case is going to be the [`<Enqueue>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/enqueue?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=feb2014&utm_campaign=stackathon) verb telling Twilio to place the call into QueueB.

Hope that helps.